# Unable to run jmeter test in docker, getting class not found exception

Tags: java, docker, jmeter

I am trying to run jmeter through docker and I am getting a class not found exception.
The maven dependency is there and I am able to run it locally with command line.

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
2021-02-13 17:48:35,315 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-2,5,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
        at Utils.TestParameters.<init>(TestParameters.java:62) ~[Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at InitTest.InitTest(InitTest.java:96) ~[Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at InitTest.runTest(InitTest.java:33) ~[Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]                                             at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JavaSampler.sample(JavaSampler.java:197) ~[ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.4.1]                                                                                                                              at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:635) ~[Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]                                                                                                                               at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) ~[Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]                                                                                                                     at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) ~[Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]                                                                                                                           at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) ~[Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_282]
```

As I said, I am able to run this locally but for the sake of this ticket, I am including
the above dependency that is in the projects pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.924</version>
</dependency>
```

My dockerfile includes the following command which copies my jar to the lib location (this jar includes the above dependency):

```
COPY Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/lib/Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I am new to docker so apologies if I am missing something basic here.

EDIT:

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# setup jmeter version to use
ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.4.1"
ARG JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION="1.3"
ARG CMDRUNNER_VERSION="2.2"
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN  ${JMETER_HOME}/bin
ENV MIRROR_HOST https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter
ENV JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL ${MIRROR_HOST}/binaries/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc
ENV JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/ext/
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN
# Install Everything.
RUN \
  sed -i -e 's/# \(.*multiverse$\)/\1/g' /etc/apt/sources.list && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y build-essential && \
  apt-get install -y software-properties-common && \
  apt-get install -y byobu openjdk-8-jre curl git htop man unzip vim wget python3-pip && \
  mkdir -p /tmp/dependencies &&   \
  curl -L --silent ${JMETER_DOWNLOAD_URL} >  /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz &&  \
  mkdir -p /opt && \
  tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}.tgz -C /opt &&  \
  rm -rf /tmp/dependencies && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
# Install jmeter lib and dependency jars
RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/jmeter-plugins-manager/${JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION}/jmeter-plugins-manager-${JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION}.jar -o ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-manager-${JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION}.jar
RUN curl -L --silent ${JMETER_PLUGINS_DOWNLOAD_URL}/cmdrunner/${CMDRUNNER_VERSION}/cmdrunner-${CMDRUNNER_VERSION}.jar -o ${JMETER_HOME}/lib/cmdrunner-${CMDRUNNER_VERSION}.jar && \
    java -cp ${JMETER_PLUGINS_FOLDER}/jmeter-plugins-manager-${JMETER_PLUGINS_MANAGER_VERSION}.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller && \
    PluginsManagerCMD.sh install jpgc-cmd=2.2,jpgc-dummy=0.4,jpgc-filterresults=2.2,jpgc-synthesis=2.2,jpgc-graphs-basic=2.0 \
    && jmeter --version \
    && PluginsManagerCMD.sh status \
RUN ln -nsf /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
RUN ln -nfs /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
RUN pip3 install awscli && pip3 install xmltodict

# sheel script has script to convert JTL to CSV
COPY run.sh /
COPY performance.jmx /performance.jmx
COPY Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/lib/Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

# Set environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Final cleanup
RUN apt-get --purge autoremove
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/run.sh"]
# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /
CMD /run.sh
```

Here is how I start jmeter:

```
echo "START Running Jmeter on `date`"

JVM_ARGS="-Xms2048m -Xmx8192m" jmeter -n -t /performance.jmx -l /jmeter.jtl 2>&1
java -jar /opt/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/lib/cmdrunner-2.2.jar --tool Reporter --plugin-type AggregateReport --input-jtl /jmeter.jtl --generate-csv /results/results.csv 2>&1
cat /results/results.csv

echo "END Running Jmeter on `date`"
```

Comment: you should show how you start jmeter, particularly how you specify the classpath because the error looks related to.

Comment: @davidxxx Added to the original post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with Docker much, but my suspicion is that the Apache Commons Logging JAR is somehow missing or not on the classpath.

The error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class <SomeClassName>` doesn't mean that the class `SomeClassName` couldn't be found.  It means that the JVM found the class but encountered an error performing static initialization.  Furthermore, this exception is only thrown if there has already been a previous failure to perform static initialization on this class.  You may or may not see a different error earlier on in your logs.

Static initialization of the class [`DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.java) consists of creating an `INSTANCE` field using instances of various classes that appear to be in the same package.  Of these, [`EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper.java) uses an Apache Commons Logging logger, but all the rest seem to only use built-in Java classes or classes in packages under `com.amazonaws`.

Static initialization for the superclass [`AWSCredentialsProviderChain`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/auth/AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java) also needs to take place, and that also includes a logger from Apache Commons Logging.

Answer (score 0):

Your ["dependency"](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) declaration doesn't necessarily mean that your `Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` will contain `aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.924.jar` (as well as its dependencies)

So I would recommend checking your `Performance-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` (.jar files are normal .zip archives) and ensure that it contains all the dependencies of the AWS Java SDK your test needs and if it doesn't - you will need to amend your pom.xml to build it as a [fat (uber) jar](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/maven/maven-build-fat-jar.html)

Alternative option is using [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin) inside your docker file, it will automatically download JMeter, plugins, dependencies, etc. so you won't have to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

As @luke-woodward suggested, the issue was eventually not with ***SomeClassName*** but with the JVM having an issue instantiating it. There was a version mismatch between different dependencies that had to be addressed. My suggestion to anyone who encounters this problem is to look for an underlying reason why ***SomeClassName*** cannot be instantiated.